# Changing prompt in While loop cycle

Tags: python-3.x

```
#CODE BLOCK 1
from pcinput import getInteger

num1 = getInteger( "Number 1: " )
num2 = getInteger( "Number 2: " )
num3 = getInteger( "Number 3: " )
num4 = getInteger( "Number 4: " )
num5 = getInteger( "Number 5: " )

print( "Total is",num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)

#CODE BLOCK 2
from pcinput import getInteger

total = 0
count = 0
while count < 5:
    total += getInteger( "Please give a number: " )
    count += 1

print( "Total is", total)
```

CODE BLOCK 1 asks the user for five numbers, and prints the total. However, that code block uses “Enter number x: ” as a prompt, whereby 'x' is a digit.

How can I change CODE BLOCK 2 so that it also uses such a changing prompt to ask for each number?

Comment: Instead of using a while-loop with a condition and remembering to increment your loop variable, you can use: `for count in range(1, 6):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total += getInteger( "Number {}: ".format(count) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total+=getInteger("Enter Number {} ".format(count+1))
```

Since variable total comes before increasing value of variable count by 1